# How to modify strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

If I have strings like this:

```
a = "11003.20140314143116.11003#13947822765031.ssint1.natvoice_nowithin_2txns.translatedalreadytotxt.pdf"
b = "11003.20140314143454.11003#13947824943836.ssint1.natvoice_nowithin_2txns.translatedalreadytotxt.pdf"
c = "11003.20140303131136.11003#13938270964818.telstra-alltxns-live_stripped-1.translatedalreadytotxt.pdf"
```

...how do I modify them in Ruby to result like this:

```
a = "ssint1.natvoice_nowithin_2txns.translatedalreadytotxt.pdf"
b = "ssint1.natvoice_nowithin_2txns.translatedalreadytotxt.pdf"
c = "telstra-alltxns-live_stripped-1.translatedalreadytotxt.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the string begin with a ~ z ?

```
result = a.gsub(/\A[^a-z]*/, '')
```

If you want the change the original string then use

```
a.gsub!(/\A[^a-z]*/, '')
```